# cross-site request

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, cross-domain-proxy

Should be done with the site number 1 request to the site number 2. Let the number one site will be localhost, and the site number 2 - the real server on the Internet. At site 2 there is a file result.php, which takes GET-requests:

`$var = @$_GET['q'] ;

 $s = $_GET['s'] ;

 $typefile = $_GET['type'];`

If the page result.php make a request, then we obtain the URL: result.php?q=%F4%FB%E2&type=1&search=%CF%EE%E8%F1%EA%21

How better to make a request? Can someone show me some examples to help? For 4 days I suffer, does not realize.

If somewhere is not clear written excuse my bad English with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean with Ajax?  You can't make cross-site domain requests through normal ajax due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  As such, a script hosted on localhost, can only make requests to localhost.

Now, you can get around this with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), or JSON with padding.  This allows you to append a script file to the dom from any source so the code can execute on your site.  Personally, I've actually never used it and I understand you have to trust the origin of the script, you don't want arbitrary code being run on your site.

So in a nutshell, if you want localhost to make a request to 'site-2' you need to host a script on 'site-2' that gets loaded by your localhost and makes the request.

Answer (score 0):

After reading what brad just said, what i would do is to add another chain to the request.

I'll be calling a local `serverside` `script` ([cross domain proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy)) that will request and process the data from the other server.

### References

- [Cross-Domain Proxy](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy)
- [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)